React JS TypeError: I6 in not a constructor
I'm new to React and Javascript. Following is a working code snippet.
import Data from '/src/assets/data/data.json';

export function DataRetriever(param) {
    if (param == 'filter-param') {
        // do some processing
        return Data;
    } else {
        throw new Error('Error message!');
    }
}

However, when I try to change data source from json to OpenSearch, I keep getting following error.
import { Client } from '@opensearch-project/opensearch';

export function DataRetriever(param) {
    // read from OpenSearch
    // do some processing
    // return Data
}

Shown in Web Console
Error: Uncaught TypeError: I6 in not a constructor in a totally unrelated file.

I would import opensearch from '@opensearch-project/opensearch'; and log what opensearch is. They might not support named exports properly for ecmascript modules.
